# Is it a correct approach to create static viewModel in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Maybe it's a simple question, but unfortunately I couldn't find a clear answer. Is it the right approach to create a static viewModel or create a ViewModel inside a static class and use it in different places?

For example, I want to show data from Serial Communication on one of my screens.

To avoid complexity, I created a simple example similar to my own project. Serial Communication started and I created a scenario as if there was a continuous data flow.

Is the following data binding correct? If not, how should the correct approach be?

Thank you in advance for your help.

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommandEvent}" Content="Click"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Counter}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

***MainWindow.cs***

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = Globals.mainWindowViewModel;
}
```

***MainWindowViewModel***

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _counter;

    public int Counter
    {
        get => _counter;
        set => SetProperty(ref _counter, value);
    }

    Communication communication = new Communication();

    public RelayCommand ButtonCommandEvent { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCommandEvent = new RelayCommand(ButtonEventClick);
    }

    private void ButtonEventClick(object param)
    {
        communication.Serial_Connect();
    }
}
```

***Communication.cs***

```
class Communication
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public void Serial_Connect()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.mainWindowViewModel.Counter = Globals.mainWindowViewModel.Counter + 1;
    }
}
```

**Globals**

```
public class Globals
{
    public static MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel { get; } = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

Comment: did you test it? should work (despite your ViewModelBase-class isn't shown here). Referencing the Globals.mainwindowViewModel in the Communication class and having an instance of it in the ViewModel again seems a little bit odd, but should work...

Comment: The code is working, but I want to make sure if what I'm doing is the right approach. If not, how should I approach?

Comment: In the actual code I do not call the Communication class again in the viewModel. Normally there is a DataReiceved and this is triggered as data comes in. I referenced it in viewModel to increase a counter in the example.

Comment: We only can see, what you show us ;-) The answer of @dhilip_h should solve the puzzle :-)

Comment: You're right, it's my fault :) Yes, I think it will work for me. I will try to adapt the answer below for my own code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your explanations are not enough for a precise answer.
To do this, we need to know why you need a global reference to the ViewModel instance.

Therefore, I will describe several options.

**1) If:**

- in general, in principle, under no circumstances is it assumed that a ViewModel can have several instances at the assembly level in which it is created;
- if this does not create any security problems, since the static instance can be accessed by everyone;
- if static values are sufficient to create a single instance. In most cases, this means that the ViewModel has only one non-parameterized constructor.

Then in this case it is worth using Singleton.

Example:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // The only instance available outside of this class.
    public static MainWindowViewModel Instanse { get; }
        = new MainWindowViewModel();

    // All constructors must be MANDATORY HIDDEN.
    private MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        // Some code
    }

    // Some code
}
```

To get this instance in XAML, x: Static is used.
You can get the entire instance, or create a binding to a separate property.

```xml
<SomeElement
    DataContext="{x:Static vm:MainWindowViewModel.Instance}"/>
<SomeElement
    Command="{Binding ButtonCommandEvent,
                      Source={x:Static vm:MainWindowViewModel.Instance}}"/>
```

**2) If:**

- ViewModel is in another assembly, it has open constructors, but the current assembly needs only one instance of it;
- if this does not create any security problems, since the static instance can be accessed by everyone;
- if static values ​​are sufficient to create a single instance. In most cases, this means that the ViewModel has only one non-parameterized constructor.

In this case, you should use a static class with a single instance.
This static class is created in the current assembly.
Usually it is a View project.
Your "class Globals" is an example of such an implementation.

Example usage in XAML:

```xml
<SomeElement
    DataContext="{x:Static local:Globals.MainWindowViewModel}"/>
<SomeElement
    Command="{Binding ButtonCommandEvent,
                      Source={x:Static local:Clobals.MainWindowViewModel}}"/>
```

**3) If:**

- instances of ViewModel can replace each other, but only one instance is used at a time;
- if this does not create any security problems, since the static instance can be accessed by everyone.

In this case, it is worth using a static class with the current instance of the ViewModel and providing notification of the replacement of this instance.

An example of such an implementation:

```cs
public static class Globals
{
    private static MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    public static MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
    {
        get => _mainWindowViewModel;
        set => Set(ref _mainWindowViewModel, value);
    }
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
    private static void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private static void Set<T>(ref T propertyFiled, in T newValue, [CallerMemberName] in string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!Equals(propertyFiled, newValue))
        {
            propertyFiled = newValue;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage in XAML:

```xml
<SomeElement
    DataContext="{Binding Path=(local:Globals.MainWindowViewModel)}"/>
<SomeElement
    Command="{Binding Path=(local:Globals.MainWindowViewModel).ButtonCommandEvent}"/>
```

**4) If** this is only needed for all windows in the application, then it is better to instantiate the ViewModel in the App Resources.

An example of such an implementation:

```xml
<Application x:Class="***.App"
             ---------------------
             --------------------->
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Example usage in XAML:

```xml
<SomeElement
    DataContext="{StaticResource mainViewModel}"/>
<SomeElement
    Command="{Binding ButtonCommandEvent,
                      Source={StaticResource mainViewModel}}"/>
```

**5) If** this is needed for all windows in the application, but you need the ability to replace an instance, or to create an instance you need a constructor with parameters that are calculated after the application starts, then it is better to create an additional class that will provide this instance and other data necessary for all Windows.

An example of such an implementation:

```cs
public class Locator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
    {
        get => _mainWindowViewModel;
        set => Set(ref _mainWindowViewModel, value);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void Set<T>(ref T propertyFiled, in T newValue, [CallerMemberName] in string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!Equals(propertyFiled, newValue))
        {
            propertyFiled = newValue;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

```xml
<Application x:Class="***.App"
             ---------------------
             --------------------->
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:Locator x:Key="locator">
            <local:Locator.MainWindowViewModel>
                <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
            </local:Locator.MainWindowViewModel>
        </local:Locator>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Or:

```xml
<Application x:Class="***.App"
             ---------------------
             ---------------------
             Startup="OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:Locator x:Key="locator"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{

    private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Locator locator = (Locator)Resources["locator"];

        // Some Code

        locator.MainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(/* Some Parameters*/);
    }
}
```

Example usage in XAML:

```xml
<SomeElement
    DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel,
                          Source={StaticResource locator}}"/>
<SomeElement
    Command="{Binding MainWindowViewModel.ButtonCommandEvent,
                      Source={StaticResource locator}"/>
```

**With regard to the "Communication" class.**
It does not work directly with UI elements, so there is no need to use a "DispatcherTimer" in it.
The main thread (namely it the DispatcherTimer uses) performs many of its tasks and does not need to load it with your tasks own unnecessarily.
Replace DispatcherTimer with any asynchronous timer:
System.Timers.Timer, System.Threading.Timer, etc.

Comment: It was a detailed and explanatory answer. Thank you for the detailed information. my purpose; Incoming data in the Communication class is to show in the user interface.
Incoming data in the Communication class are different data on different pages that the User will see.

Comment: The "Communication" class only modifies the properties of the regular class.
Properties of this (mutable) class are displayed by UI elements via Bindings and, accordingly, listen for the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event.
When this event is received, it is automatically marshaled to the UI thread of the element.
Therefore, there is no need to change the values ​​of ordinary properties in the UI thread.

Comment: Not for this occasion, but for the future.
For IComand.CanCommandChanged and INotifyPCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged, you need to marshal yourself.
But this is usually done in a type that implements these interfaces.

Comment: According to what I understood from your explanations and code, in my opinion, the implementation of Singleton will be the simplest and most convenient for you.

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I applied the first case to my code and it struck me.

Answer (score -1):

You must have an event in the Communication class and subscribe to that event from the **MainWindowViewModel** constructor. Then invoke the event in the **DispatcherTimer_Tick** method.

Or simply use something like Prism's **PubSubEvent** class

Communication Class -

```
class Communication
{
    public event EventHandler OnTickEvent;

    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public void Serial_Connect()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnTickEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel class -

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _counter;

    public int Counter
    {
        get => _counter;
        set => SetProperty(ref _counter, value);
    }

    Communication communication = new Communication();

    public RelayCommand ButtonCommandEvent { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCommandEvent = new RelayCommand(ButtonEventClick);
        communication.OnTickEvent += Communication_OnTickEvent;
    }

    private void Communication_OnTickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Counter += 1;
    }

    private void ButtonEventClick(object param)
    {
        communication.Serial_Connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do the application in your first suggestion? Unfortunately, I don't understand how I can change the counter variable in this case.

Comment: the Communication class might have a custom Eventhandler implemented, the tick would fire this and the Counter++ would happen on the ViewModel-level

Comment: Thanks @dhilip_h, I think this is what I was looking for. I will try right away.

Comment: How can I subscribe to @dhilip_h, `SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) { }` function? I think the above example only applies to TimerTick.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I don't find this function in the code that you've shared in your question. If your question is about using a custom EventArgs class, then you must use the generic type of EventHandler class. For example, your event declaration must be like this - `public event EventHandler<SerialDataReceivedEventArgs> OnDataReceivedEvent;`